# Change emacs indentation for cmake?

Tags: emacs, cmake

For the LIFE of me I can't figure out why emacs indents lines in *.cmake files with 2 spaces per indent rather than what the Standard Indent is set to in customize. I also have `c-basic-offset` set to 4. I can't find anything with apropos help, google, `C-h C-m`...

EVERYTHING ELSE works with indentation spacing of 4 -- python, c++, etc. Why does cmake indent to 2 spaces while everything else does 4? How can I change it back to use 4 spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a quick look at `cmake-mode`, `cmake-tab-width` is the variable you want to change.
Try `(setq cmake-tab-width 4)` somewhere in your Emacs startup files.

This is with Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 14.04; cmake-mode.el seems to come from CMake 2.8.12.2 (all stock Ubuntu provided packages).